# heroku app iframe abnormality

Tags: facebook, canvas, heroku

When I load up my app, either stand-alone or inside Facebook canvas, theres an iframe with a inline height and width property that's basically blocking all app links and functions because It's somehow sitting on top of everything.

I'm not an experienced Facebook app developer and was wondering what's going on and how to handle it? I've identified the css in Google Chrome but don't know how to remove or prevent the styles since the iframe is not part of the dev package I cloned. The app is up on Facebook and should be viewable using facebook.apps.com/datingfordummies

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. I simply removed the width and height property in my css. I would have done this initially but was afraid it would effect the other iframes on the page. Needless to say, it didn't and is now working.

for future reference:

```
iframe{width:0 !important; height:0 !important;}
```